# Why is camera still working after cv2 release?

Tags: video, opencv, python

I'm using spyder to capture frames from my camera (A4tech PK-910H).

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After pressing 'q' there is no error, but the camera still shines blue indicating that is still working. After restarting kernel in Spyder (3.3.1), camera turns off.
How can I turn it off without restarting kernel?

Comment: what happens if you put `cap.release()` outside of the condition just before `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` ?

Comment: Hi, it's the same. I've put it inside, for that reason actually.

Comment: what OS are you on ? Also: do you run into the same issue when you run the script outside of Spyder (just plain command line) ?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. In anaconda prompt:

>>> import cv2
>>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
>>> ret, frame = cap.read()
>>> cap.release()
>>> exit()

the camera didn't shut down after cap.release() but it did after exiting python

Comment: The same camera and the same script on Spyder is working fine on Linux Mint

Comment: Same here with Windows 10 + Python 2.7 + OpenCV 3.4.3 The camera shuts down upon exiting Idle but not after `release()` or after exiting program.